# data chart doesn't function

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I want to use a chart with Angular. When I enter the raw data, the graph appears but I can not recover the data dynamically via my API. I tried in the ngOnInit to use a console.log and I successfully retrieved the data from the API.
The problem is when I want to assign the data to the chart.

Component TS :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { PageTitleService } from '../../core/page-title/page-title.service';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { StatistiqueService } from 'app/service/statistique/statistique.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'ms-charts',
  templateUrl:'./statstypedemande-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./statstypedemande-component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  
})

export class StatsTypeDemandeComponent implements OnInit {

   stats: number[];
   statistiques: [];

   constructor(private pageTitleService: PageTitleService,
               public translate: TranslateService,
               private serviceStatistique : StatistiqueService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.translate.get('Statistique des types de demandes').subscribe((res: string) => {
        this.pageTitleService.setTitle(res);
      });

      this.serviceStatistique.getTest()
      .subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res);
         this.stats = res;
         console.log(this.stats);

      })      
   }

      // Doughnut
      public doughnutChartLabels = ['Entreprise', 'Salarié', 'Particulier'];
      public doughnutChartColors: any[] = [{ backgroundColor: ["#b8436d", "#00d9f9", "#a4c73c"] }];
      //public doughnutChartData:number[] = [350, 450, 100];
      public doughnutChartData:number[] = this.stats;
      public doughnutChartType:string = 'doughnut';

}
```

Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StatistiqueService {

  readonly rootURL = 'https://localhost:44319/api';
  list : number[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTest()
  {
      return this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/Demande/StatsTypeDemande');
  }
}
```

Componement HTML :

```
<!--Ng2 Charts-->
<div class="row">
    <!-- Doughnut Chart -->

    <div *ngFor="let a of stats">
        {{ a }}
    </div>   

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="chk-block">
            <div class="chk-block-title">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-row">
                        <h3>Statistique des types de demande</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chk-block-content">
                <canvas baseChart height="100" [data]="doughnutChartData" [options]="PieChartOptions" [colors]="doughnutChartColors" [chartType]="doughnutChartType" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Row Closed -->
```

Comment: Please provide contents of the "./statstypedemande-component.html". Also which library do you use for the doughnut chart?

Comment: @Krypt1 I use Ng2-Chart for the doughnut chart.
I have edit my post to add the contents of  the "./statstypedemande-component.html".
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

In your template you use `doughnutChartData` field to bind data from component to the chart. During the initialization you set it to the `this.stats` field, which **doesn't contain anything** at that time:

```
public doughnutChartData:number[] = this.stats;
```

When your data is loaded from the API, you set it to the `this.stats` field:

```
this.serviceStatistique.getTest()
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.stats = res;
    console.log(this.stats);
  })
```

But the `doughnutChartData` field (which is used in the template) is still pointing to the **undefined** value of the old `this.stats`.

**Either** remove `this.stats` and set data directly to the `doughnutChartData` field:

```
this.serviceStatistique.getTest()
  .subscribe(res => this.doughnutChartData = res)
```

**Or** remove `doughnutChartData` and update template to use `stats` field instead:

```
<canvas baseChart
  height="100"
  [data]="stats"
  [options]="PieChartOptions"
  [colors]="doughnutChartColors"
  [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
  [labels]="doughnutChartLabels">
</canvas>
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-question-55759276)

Comment: I have test your idea but I have this error :
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

I have an other problem in Visual Studio too :
"The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more."

Thank you for your help

Comment: @PierreLaurent This is probably a problem with data from the API. Could you provide stack trace and response from the service?

Comment: I tested my API with Postman and I get the following result: [
2,
1,
0
]
I think the problem is that the API method returns an object and the chart expects an array of int

Comment: @PierreLaurent I've added an example on StackBlitz, please check that out. On a side note I've noticed another error, unrelated to the data. You have `PieChartOptions` field used in the template, but the component doesn't have that field. Might be a mechanical error when you've copied the sources here, just letting you know.

Comment: @PierreLaurent Ah, type error is happening because of the TypeScript, it should still work. You can fix this if you would add generic parameter to the service: 
`return this.http.get<number[]>(this.rootURL + '/Demande/StatsTypeDemande');`. Also I'm guessing that you would probably want to hide the chart until data is loaded using `*ngIf="doughnutChartData"`.